# Load glTF with instanced Meshs into Aframe

Tags: aframe, gltf

I've got a glTF file with instanced meshs exported from Blender. My Problem is, that Aframe does not accept the instancing and draws every piece without instancing, which causes the browser memory to crash. In the glTF viewer (https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) it works without problems. How do I import this file properly, so that Aframe can visualize it?

I am using the standard a-gltf-model tag in Aframe.

Edit:
So basically I got something standard like this:

```
<a-scene>
    <a-assets timeout="40000">
    <a-asset-item id="r" src="path/to/my/model.gltf"  ></a-asset-item>

    </a-assets>
     <a-gltf-model src="#r" scale="0.4 0.4 0.4" position="1 1 1">
    </a-gltf-model>     
    <a-camera id="camera" cursor-visible="true" cursor-opacity="1" position="3.083 0.957 -1.607"></a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

Problem is now, that the model is created with instancing in blender and Aframe doesnt multiply the instanced versions of the model over and over. It starts to draw every instance as a single model, which causes the browser to crash. Its a model of a piece of gras, which should be spread over a plane, without drawing the 7k vertices for every single piece. In Don McCurdys glTF viewer its loading immediately and working as it should, looking like this:
[image]

The normal version looks like this in Aframe:
[image]

EDIT 2:

Here is a working Glitch example (somehow it doesn't crash). It loads, but as you can see in the Inspector the draw and triangle calls are rising, which they shouldn't. 
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/instance-gltf

EDIT 3: So apparently glTF is capable of instancing and the from blender exported file should work, but doesn't. As we did it like this. [Source](http://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/issues/203).

Comment: If you share a simple A-Frame scene loading your model will help people to help you

Comment: Problem is it doesnt load, because of a memory crash. It doesn't apply the instancing. I can try to provide screenshots, how it should look like. It's a little hard for me to explain, maybe I just PM you.

Comment: edited the post with some more information

Comment: Sharing a runnable example will help people investigate (even if it crashes). Better to do it publicly I don’t have all the answers. Glitch is a good option https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: Okay, I will set one up!

Comment: Glitch example is added in EDIT 2 :)

Comment: I see same results in gltf-viewer and A-Frame glitch. AFAIK, the THREE gltf-loader is not yet honoring instancing and meshes are rendered separately. You can for now join / merge the meshes on the Blender side. It will produce a larger file but will give you the draw calls savings.

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh this was the base for my efforts to integrate instancing in aframe

Comment: So it seems like glTF is capable of creating instanced meshs https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/issues/203 and there should be a way aframe can display it instanced I guess.

Comment: glTF spec supports instancing. The [THREE glTF loader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/e6551ef98a75a5d53aa2b490cb5d121c37dc850f/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js) that both A-Frame and the glTFViewer use not yet

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! :)